# Amazon AWS / Rakuten API - Inventory Management

Tags: amazon-web-services, inventory

I am sure this question may seem a bit lacking, but I literally do not know where to begin with. I want to develop a solution that will allow me to manage **ALL** of my **Amazon** and **Rakuten/Buy.com** inventory from my own website.

My main concern is keeping the inventory in sync, so the process would be as follows:

1.Fetch Orders sold today
a.Subtract the respective quantities

2.Fetch Rakuten orders sold
a.Subtract the respective quantities

3.Update Internal DB of products
a.Send out updated feeds to Amazon and Rakuten.

Again, I apologize if this question may seem a bit lacking, but I am having trouble understanding how exactly to implement this, any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For the Amazon part look at https://developer.amazonservices.com/

Rakuten, I think you will be able to do what you want with it via the FTP access, I'm still researching this.  If I find more I'll respond with a better answer.

Comment: And ditto for @Brad's answer.  It was perhaps a hint, something else to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

In order to process orders, you'll need to use be registered with Rakuten in order to get an authorisation token.  For the API doc etc... try sending an email to support@rakuten.co.uk.

Incidentally, to send out updated feeds, you'll need to use the inventory API in order to update stock quantities (given that you'll be selling the same item Amazon etc..).

Comment: Why was my answer marked down?  What you asked is what I've done professionally, and thus I answer your question succinctly.